# How to change data structure in mysql using mysqldump without deleting files

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

Essentially what I'm trying to do is sync a **production server** with a **sandbox server**, but only the table structures and stored procedures. The procedures aren't any problem since they can be overriden, but the problem is the tables. I want to sync and alter their structures on the production server using `mysqldump` (or any other way that you can propose) **without** altering any existing data.

If it helps, I only want to add more columns, not remove any existing ones. Also, I am using `mysqlyog`.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

As long as you don't rename tables and columns and you are not using partitions you might use [schemasync](https://github.com/mmatuson/SchemaSync) .

Basic usage is:

```
schemasync mysql://user:pass@dev-host:3306/dev_db mysql://user:pass@prod-host:3306/prod_db
```

This will produce two SQL scripts - one for "patching" the production database, and another one for reverting the changes.

Please note that schema altering will lock the tables being affected, so you will have some downtime anyway. There are tools to avoid this: [pt-online-schema-change](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-online-schema-change.html) from Percona and [oak-online-alter-table](http://openarkkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/openarkkit/doc/html/oak-online-alter-table.html) from openarkkit.

Also, as with any possibly destructive changes, test the procedure on a staging (or other non-production use, but production data and schema) database.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to update only the table structure from the sandbox to the production, you need to ensure that you do not accidentally damage the production database:

a) Dump the production database structure into a staging database

mysqldump -R --add-drop-table --no-data -h productionhostname -u productionUSER -pproductionPASSWORD productiondbname | mysql -u stagingUSER -pstagingPASSWORD -h staginghostname stagingdatabasename

b) Use a tool like [SQL Yog](http://www.webyog.com) or [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) to generate a script to update the structure of the staging database from the sandbox

c) Test the generated script on the staging database

d) Execute the generated script on the production database.

I am not sure if this process can be automated since at times phyiscal database changes need accompanying data updates

Answer (score 0):

1. export data from parent server and remove the table.
2. import only table structure from sandbox into production.
3. now once again import data into production

   keep backup of your db ;

Comment: Thank you for your answer Arun. Unfortunately this will result in a server downtime which is what I'm trying to avoid. :(

If I can't come up with anything then I will have to go with your solutions though, so thank you.

Comment: u can create as temp and rename once you are finished ,so downtime will be only seconds.